# Is the value of Time.time invoked in Start always equal to one invoked in the first call of Update?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know whether the value of `Time.time` invoked in the first call of `Update` is guaranteed to be equal to one invoked in `Start` as follows.

```
public class Common : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float t;
    void Start()
    {
        t = Time.time;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log($"{t == Time.time }");    
    }
}
```

I do several tries and I get almost identical results as follows.
Surprisingly the values in the first two calls of `Update` are also identical to one invoked in `Start`.

[image]

## Question

Is the value of `Time.time` in `Start` guaranteed to be equal to one invoked in the first call of `Update`? I ask this because in my real scenario I need to know this to avoid unexpected results that I cannot produce right now.

## Edit

Even I add `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to the `Start`, I still don't notice any differences.

Comment: What do you need it for exactly? Note that `Regular (per frame) calls should be avoided`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it is not.**

[`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) occurs **before** the first frame, while the first [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) call **is** the first frame.

[`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) is just the current time since the beginning of program execution, updated at the start of every frame, so if in your [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html)you have large amounts of code which slow your processor, there will be noticeable differences between the [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) call in [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and the one in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html).

Check out the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: I don't see any difference even I add a heavy workload in the `Start`. I simulated the workload with `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. See my edit.

Comment: You never added anything to print the result of that first Time.Time Call in start though

Answer (score -1):

No, they are not equal,
maybe in most of the times, you get same results, but it's not guaranteed to happen every time.
`Start` and `Update` are two different functions, It's important to know they are not called exactly after each other. So many things can affect their call-time.
In [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) you can see these functions, so Heavy Physics, Number of animations, graphic's frame rate and... may be different in different Hardwares.

Comment: Why did you post almost identical  contents as the previous one?

Comment: I wrote about the reason ;)